# Saving video from shared photostream

Tags: ios, ipad, photos, photos.app, photo-stream

How do I copy or save a video on a shared photostream to my iPad camera roll? Tapping on the video does not offer a suitable choice. Mail a copy is ghosted out.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the video you wish to save.
2. Tap the **Share** <sub>[image]</sub> button
3. Select **Save Video** in the actions list (bottom scroll view, may have to scroll to the right).